# SQL Query: list of all maximal reservers

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following schemas:

```
sailor: ssn, fname, lname, address
reservation: sailor_ssn, date_reserved, boat_reg#
boat: reg#, bname, color, model#
```

I want to list the names of all maximal reservers. A sailor is a maximal reserver if the set of boat(s) he has reserved is not a proper subset of any other sailors.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following query:

```
SELECT p.fname, p.lname 
FROM sail.person p
JOIN sail.sailor s ON p.ssn = s.ssn
JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT r4.sailor_ssn 
     FROM sail.reservation r4
     WHERE r4.sailor_ssn NOT IN
        (SELECT T3.sailor_ssn
         FROM
            (SELECT *
             FROM 
                (SELECT r1.sailor_ssn, r2.sailor_ssn sssn, count(*) ctr1
                 FROM sail.reservation r1
                 JOIN sail.reservation r2 ON r1.boat_reg# = r2.boat_reg# 
                 AND r1.sailor_ssn != r2.sailor_ssn
                 GROUP BY r1.sailor_ssn, r2.sailor_ssn) T1 
                 JOIN 
                    (SELECT r3.sailor_ssn rssn, count(*) ctr2
                     FROM sail.reservation r3
                     GROUP BY r3.sailor_ssn) T2 
                 ON T1.sailor_ssn = T2.rssn) T3
         where T3.ctr1 = T3.ctr2)) T4
ON T4.sailor_ssn = s.ssn;
```

Is there any better solution?